# Is there an easier way, that would be understandable for beginners?

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I found this **menu** that displays **border at bottom**, i would like to learn how to do it, but i don't understand how its done, is there an easier way that the same thing would be achieved?
Here is the URL: https://codepen.io/atomas/pen/zBoEZe?editors=1100

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <li class="elm selected">Home</li>
  <li class="elm">Services</li>
  <li class="elm">About</li>
  <li class="elm bar">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
$elementsNumber: 4; 
$width: 1/$elementsNumber;


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul { 
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #000;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow: hidden;

  li {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: percentage($width);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #555;



  }
      .bar:before {
      overflow: hidden;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 54px;
      bottom: 0;
      transition: all 0.25s;
      left: 0;
      width: percentage($width);
      height: 4px;
      background: red;
    }


}

@for $i from 1 through $elementsNumber {

    li:nth-child( #{$i} ) {
      &.selected~.bar:before,
      &.elm:hover~.bar:before,      
      &.selected.bar:before,
      &.elm.bar:hover:before
       {
        left: percentage( ( $i - 1 ) * $width );
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {  box-sizing: border-box;}
ul { 
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #000;
  }
li {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
  
    border-bottom: 4px solid #555; 
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
li:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="elm selected">Home</li>
  <li class="elm">Services</li>
  <li class="elm">About</li>
  <li class="elm bar">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks thats what i was searching for, do you maybe know how to add that animation on hover? sorry if i ask to much :D

Comment: it seems to be no easier way that the same thing would be achieved

Answer (score 0):

If you'd just want a *border* on the *bottom* of the menu you can just use `border-bottom:`

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: #eee;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
}
ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
ul>li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
ul>li>a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
ul>li:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #555;
    margin-bottom: -5px
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Sorry but that is not what i am looking for, i want the same thing like on the link, not just a border on bottom of ul, but thanks anyhow :D

Comment: What _do_ you want then? What other border at the bottom? You mean the one _selected_ ?

Comment: The border at the bottom of li, so when i hover over li it displays the red line on that grey that you made...

Answer (score 0):

That css does a lot more than just adding a border at the bottom.

The grey border you see at the bottom is displayed through:

```
li {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: percentage($width);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    ***border-bottom: 4px solid #555***;
  }
```

However, the css also adds a component which highlights the specific li element which is being hovered over to make the border-bottom red.

The width property at the top just makes sure each li element gets equal space horizontally in the browser:

```
$elementsNumber: 4; 
$width: 1/$elementsNumber;
```

In order to achieve the same red hover as your codepen illustrates, you will need to write some css such as li:hover etc. to mimic the same effect.

That css you have is definitely more complicated than it needs to be but works for the intended purpose. Taking a look at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) link here should help you understand the hover property and other useful properties in CSS.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, it helped :D